# How to Change an Index in one form from another form according to user selection in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

In Form1 I have set comboBox.SelectedIndex as Index 0 (comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;). This is the code of it.

public void FORM1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        comboBox.Items.Insert(0, "Customer Name");
        comboBox.Items.Insert(1, "Customer ID");
        comboBox.Items.Insert(2, "Phone Number");
        comboBox.Items.Insert(3, "Email");

        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }
```

Then I want to change the above index according to user's selection from the menubar of MDI Form.

Ex:- If user Selected "Search Customer By ID" From the menu bar of MDI Form, above value should be change to 1.

I used following method. but it was unsuccessful

```
    private void byIDToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmSearchCustomer frm = new frmSearchCustomer();
        frm.comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        frm.ShowDialog();


    }
```

Please give me a correct programming code to fulfill my requirement.
Thank you

Comment: What is the name of the combo? cmbSearchBy or combobox?

Comment: The above code appears like correct from what you mentioned. Is this not serving what you are expecting?

Comment: The Name of ComboBox is "cmbSearchBy".

Comment: @Naresh> No. It gives an error message

Comment: That's not what your first snippet says, it uses "comboBox".  You'll need to make up your mind what the real name is.  Set the Modifiers property of the control to Public.

Comment: @HansPassant> Yes. I put it as combobox.Items.... to give an understanding to others, it is a combo box. But in 2nd code I couldn't change it.
Anyway In my Coding I put is as "cmbSearchBy" [i.e :- cmbSearchBy.Items.Insert(0, "Customer Name");]

Comment: @HansPassant> Ok. I corrected that mistake. Thanks for showing me it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the form containing the combobox change the code to

```
public int UserSelectedIndex { get; set;}

public void FORM1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        comboBox.Items.Insert(0, "Customer Name");
        comboBox.Items.Insert(1, "Customer ID");
        comboBox.Items.Insert(2, "Phone Number");
        comboBox.Items.Insert(3, "Email");

        comboBox.SelectedIndex = UserSelectedIndex;

    }
```

Form the MDI form you can now set the selected Index

```
private void byIDToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmSearchCustomer frm = new frmSearchCustomer();
        frm.UserSelectedIndex = 1;
        frm.ShowDialog();


    }
```

Comment: Thanks r.net. It's working now. :)
And Thank you all for supported me.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you do make an effort to understand why your code was not working. The FORM_Load event is called after you set the value to 1 which was re-setting the value of the combo box back to 0.

Comment: > Yes. Actually I tried the whole day to doing that. But I couldn't. Anyway Now I know the resaon. Thanks a lot again. :)